# React Memo updating Parent component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, rerender, react-memo

I have components like below

`QuestionAnsPage.component(parent)`:

```
export interface FieldsDatatype {
  id: string | number;
  attributeId: string | number,
  mainQuestionFlg?: boolean;
  mainQuestionId: number | string,
  question: string;
  **values: Array<number | string>;**
  fieldType: number;
  mandatory: boolean;
  isNumber: boolean;
  pattern?: string;
  max?: string | number;
  min?: string | number;
  displayInline?: boolean;
  error?: boolean;
  message?: string;
  options: OptionsType[] | undefined | null;
  storedColumn?: string;
  storedJson?: string;
}

type Props = {
  data?: FieldsDatatype[];
  country: string;
  handleOnConfirmClick: (data: FieldsDatatype[]) => void;
  handleOnCancelClick: () => void;
  isLoading?: boolean;
  errorMessage?: Error;
  id: string | number;
}
const QuestionAnsPageComponent = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.data) {
          setData(props.data);
        }
      }, [props.data]);
.
.
..
}
```

My QuestionAnswer.componet(child):

```
type Props = {
  data: FieldsDatatype;
  onChange?: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  onChangeSelect?: (id: string | number, value: string | number) => void;
  onDateChange?: (fieldName: string | number, value: string) => void;
  onBlur?: (event: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLButtonElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void;
  country: string;
}

   const QuestionAnswerComponent = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
    function comparisonForRerender(prevProps: Props, nextProps: Props): boolean {
         console.log('nextProps:', nextProps.data.values, nextProps.data.id);
         console.log('prevProps:', prevProps.data.values, prevProps.data.id);
      const nextValArr = [...nextProps.data.values];
      const prevValArr = prevProps.data ? [...prevProps.data.values] : [];
      const nextValuesLen = nextValArr.length;
      const prevValuesLen = prevValArr.length;
      if (nextValArr
        && prevValArr
        && nextValuesLen > 1
        && nextProps.data.fieldType === FIELDS_TYPE.CHECKBOX) {
        return (nextValuesLen === prevValuesLen
              && JSON.stringify(prevValArr) === JSON.stringify(prevValArr));
      } else if (nextValArr
        && prevValArr
        && nextValuesLen > 0
        && prevValuesLen > 0
        && nextProps.data.id === prevProps.data.id) {
        **return (prevValArr.includes(nextValArr[0]));**
      }
      return false;
    }
    }

    export default React.memo(QuestionAnswerComponent, comparisonForRerender);
```

I am using this `React.memo` for performance improvement. I want to render my child component when `"props.data.values"` (type of this field is `Array<string | number>`) changes. for that purpose I have created `comparisonForRerender` function.

I am trying to compare `props.data.value` in function like :`(prevValArr.includes(nextValArr[0]))`

But this function causing some weird behavior, my parent component state get reset to old value some how(data in this case).

I am not sure but this comparison function somehow changing my parent component state.
If I remove this function then it is working fine.

Comment: I have no idea what exactly is your question. Please, state what you are trying to achieve a little more clearly.

Comment: I have updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent component is being updated because `props.data` is an array.
Only the pointer of the array is checked in the dependency array, of the `useEffect` function, you'll need to compare value of every element in the array, or choose a different a dependency variable, maybe something like the length of the array.